# How to create session level table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I am working on an application using Spring, Hibernate, and PostgreSQL 9.1. The requirement is user can upload bulk data from the browser.

Now the data getting uploaded by each user is very crude and requires lots of validation before it can be put into the actual transaction table. I want a temporary table to be created whenever a user uploads; after data is successfully dumped into this temp table, I will call a procedure to perform the actual work of validating and taking the data from the temp table to the transaction table. If anywhere error is encountered then I will dump logs to any other table so the user can know the status of their upload from the browser.

In PostgreSQL do we have anything like temporary, session-level table?

Comment: Why do you need a table per uploaded file? Why not store all the files in the same table?

Comment: Echo JB Nizat...a table with a 'file_id' column would make more sense then constantly creating a temp table for each users upload...stored procedures are hard to get to handle dynamic temp table naming.  But I'm assuming you have a dynamic number of columns being uploaded by each user (so you need dynamic column names, hence a temp table).  Not an easy task and might be best handled by rethinking the user req...is this a one time data load/initialize or is this an ongoing process?  I'd strongly recommend revisiting the user req if this is to be an on-going process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the 9.1 manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html):

```
CREATE [ [ GLOBAL | LOCAL ] { TEMPORARY | TEMP } | UNLOGGED ] TABLE [ IF NOT EXISTS ] table_name ( [
  { column_name data_type [ COLLATE collation ] [ column_constraint [ ... ] ]
    | table_constraint
    | LIKE parent_table [ like_option ... ] }
    [, ... ]
] )
[ INHERITS ( parent_table [, ... ] ) ]
[ WITH ( storage_parameter [= value] [, ... ] ) | WITH OIDS | WITHOUT OIDS ]
[ ON COMMIT { PRESERVE ROWS | DELETE ROWS | DROP } ]
[ TABLESPACE tablespace ]
```

The key word here is TEMPORARY although it is not necessary to the table to be temporary. It could be a permanent table that you truncate before inserting. The whole operation (inserting and validating) would have to be wrapped in a transaction.